# Let $L = \{f:X \to [0, 1] \mid f \text{ is measurable}\}$. Then $\mu_+(X) = \sup_{f \in L} \int_X f \mathrm d \mu$

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, signed-measures

I'm trying to prove this characterization. Could you have a check if my attempt is fine?

---

> Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mu$ a **signed** Borel measure on $X$. Let $\mu = \mu_+ - \mu_-$ be the Jordan decomposition of $\mu$. Let $L = \{f:X \to [0, 1] \mid f \text{ is measurable}\}$. Then
> $$
> \mu_+(X) = \sup_{f \in L} \int_X f \mathrm d \mu.
> $$

**My attempt:** We have
$$
\begin{align}
\mu_+ (X) &= \sup \{\mu(B) \mid B \in \mathcal B (X)\} \\
&= \sup_{B \in \mathcal B (X)} \int_X 1_B \mathrm d \mu \\
&\le \sup_{f \in L} \int_X f \mathrm d \mu \quad \text{because} \quad 1_B \in L.
\end{align}
$$

On the other hand,
$$
\begin{align}
\sup_{f \in L} \int_X f \mathrm d \mu &= \sup_{f \in L} \int_X f \mathrm d (\mu_+ - \mu_-) \\
&= \sup_{f \in L} \left ( \int_X f \mathrm d \mu_+ - \int_X f \mathrm d \mu_- \right )\\
&\le \sup_{f \in L} \int_X f \mathrm d \mu_+  \\
&\le \int_X  \mathrm d \mu_+ \\
&= \mu_+ (X).
\end{align}
$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: Looks fine to me.